# Using validity.customError or hacking validity to run specific JS function

Tags: javascript, html

I'm creating an input field of type text and I want to use the HTML validity to run a JS function as the validity check. How is validity.customError used, or how can I achieve this?

Thanks - Caius

Answer (score 2):

To trigger `validity.customError` you should set `element.setCustomValidity(message)` in an `oninput` or `onsubmit` event.  [Here's a simple example](http://jsfiddle.net/robertc/PHdz7/), first the form:

```
<form target="#" method="post" >
    <label>Enter Rob: <input id="rob" required></label>
    <br/>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Here's the JS, jQuery is used for event binding:

```
$('form').bind('input', function() {
    var r = $('#rob')[0];
    if (r.value !== 'Rob') {
        r.setCustomValidity('You did not enter Rob');
    } else {
        r.setCustomValidity('');
    }
});
```

Comment: If you need to retrieve the error message for a field, use `r.validationMessage`.